# System.Management.ManagementException: Not found

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem on Windows XP regarding my application. I am receiving the following error on Windows XP, while on 7/8 it works fine and I have no idea what to do next. I looked into this issue and found out it is related with WMI. I tried repairing WMI on the Windows XP system but it still did not work.

This is the error I am receiving:

> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.Management.ManagementException: Not found     at
>   System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus
>   errorCode)    at System.Management.PropertyData.RefreshPropertyInfo() 
>   at System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Item(String propertyName)
>   at ?.?.(Object , EventArgs )    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

winmgmt service is running on the said system. Does anyone have any idea on what to do next? I am currently installing Windows XP in order to pin-point the bug, but I could use some help from more experienced members of this site.

Here's the code that simulates the error. It halts on the hdd.Get loop

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Starting process"
        Try
            Dim HDD_Serial As String = Nothing
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 1"
            Dim hdd As New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 2"
            For Each hd In hdd.Get
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 2.x"
                HDD_Serial = hd("SerialNumber")
            Next
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 3"
            HDD_Serial = HDD_Serial.Replace(" ", "")
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 4"
            Dim regkey As String = "0000-0000-0000-0000"
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 5"
            Dim sstring As String = regkey + "|" + HDD_Serial
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 6"
            sstring = AESEncrypt(sstring, "4545664456", "1251545478")
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 7"
            sstring = StrToHex(sstring)
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 8"
            Dim rk2 As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Test Key")
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 9"
            rk2.SetValue("regentry", sstring, RegistryValueKind.String)
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "Step 10"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error")
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------" + vbNewLine + ex.ToString
        End Try
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + "End of log"
    End Sub
```

Image of the error:

[image]

Comment: The error occurs when the user tries to activate their product by typing in the serial key, therefor I cannot share much of the code that's causing it. I will however add more code tomorrow once I setup Windows XP on my system.

Comment: Lots of changes in WMI after XP.  The simple explanation is that you use a property that isn't available.  Don't keep your query a secret.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass that somehow? I will post code tomorrow cause I'm not on my PC at this moment, also I have to run it on XP to see on which line precisely it's happening, although I have a general idea where it may be. Thanks for the input tho.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code that I used to simulate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround for this. I first detected what Windows version is running and then in case of Windows XP I used an API call instead of WMI to gain HDD ID. In case the version is above XP I used WMI. My application is using NET Framework 4.0 so I don't need to check for earlier versions of Windows.

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetVolumeInformation(ByVal PathName As String, ByVal VolumeNameBuffer As StringBuilder, ByVal VolumeNameSize As Int32, ByRef VolumeSerialNumber As Int32, ByRef MaximumComponentLength As Int32, ByRef FileSystemFlags As Int32, ByVal FileSystemNameBuffer As StringBuilder, ByVal FileSystemNameSize As Int32) As Long
    End Function

    Friend Function GetVolumeSerial(ByVal strDriveLetter As String) As String

        Dim serNum As System.Int32 = 0
        Dim maxCompLen As System.Int32 = 0
        Dim VolLabel As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(256)
        Dim VolFlags As Int32 = New Int32
        Dim FSName As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(256)
        strDriveLetter += ":\"
        Dim Ret As Long = GetVolumeInformation(strDriveLetter, VolLabel, CType(VolLabel.Capacity, Int32), serNum, maxCompLen, VolFlags, FSName, CType(FSName.Capacity, Int32))
        Return Convert.ToString(serNum)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the serial number in the same format as you would get if from WMI "VolumeSerialNumber" use the following

```
Return Convert.ToString(serNum, 16).ToString.ToUpper
```

this will give you the hexadecimal string....